# Python - How do I wait for server response using requests

Tags: python

I use the following code to retrieve a web page.

```
import requests
payload = {'name': temp} #I extract temp from another page.
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0','Accept': 'text/html, */*; q=0.01','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' }
full_url = url.rstrip() + '/test/log?'
r = requests.get(full_url, params=payload, headers=headers, stream=True)                    
for line in r.iter_lines():
   if line:
    print line
```

However for some reason the http response is lacking the text inside  tags.
I found out that if I send the request to Burp, intercept it and wait for 3 secs before forwarding it, then I get the complete html page containing the text inside the  tags....
I still could not find the cause. Ideas?

Comment: `requests.get` is synchronous, it waits for the response by itself. What is Burp?

Comment: Burp is  proxy software

Comment: Are you first sending a request that's supposed to update data on the server, then sending a second request to get the results? Maybe the first request hasn't finished yet.

Comment: Is the text produced by javascript?  I'm guessing Burp is getting the resulting page, and so you see the text.  BS doesn't deal with javascript created html

Comment: As @abc is implying below, you are explicitly setting the `stream` parameter to `True`, which is causing your undesired behavior.

Comment: The odd part is that if I replay the same request, crafted with the above code, using Burp i get the whole page. To me it seems a problem of incomplete response. Is there any way to wait until I get all the data?

Comment: So the difference is whether you go through Burp or go directly to the server?

Comment: Just changed Stream to False and same issue

Comment: @Barmar not really. As I see broken response in Burp if I don't intercept my request and wait for some time.

Comment: @acemutha Can you give your url ?

Comment: You never answered my earlier question. Is the request expecting to get something that results from a previous request? You may not be allowing time for the previous request to finish updating the server.

Comment: @Barmar. Yes I am (trying to) reading the output from a script executed on server side. And I am triggering it with another request

Comment: It would be better if the first request simply returned its output directly, instead of requiring you to make a second request. If the first request returns before the results are ready, there's no reliable way to know how long to wait before making the second request.

Comment: But I guess you could put a 3-second sleep in your Python script.

Comment: @Barmar I did but still no luck... Maybe I need to add it in several sections

Comment: Are you waiting for the first request to return before making the second request?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between a 3-second delay in Burp and a delay in Python. If the first works, so should the second.

Comment: Not explicitly... Is there a way to do it without using threads?

Comment: But in Burp you can send the request and put a delay before receiving the response. Where would I put such delay in my code?.

Answer (score 0):

From requests documentation:

> By default, when you make a request, the body of the response is
>   downloaded immediately. You can override this behaviour and defer
>   downloading the response body until you access the Response.content
>   attribute with the stream parameter:

[Body Content Workflow](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/)

In other words try removing `stream=True` in your `requests.get()`

or

You will have all the content when you access `r.content`, where `r` is the response.

Comment: How does this change whether the response body contains the contents of the tags or not?

Comment: Could you rephrase? Not sure I get what you mean

Comment: @abc. Sorry cannot give it as it is using internal IP